# Prefuse - is it possible to translate keys used in legend?

Tags: java, translation, prefuse

I'm using prefuse library for Java.

Everything seems to be working fine, however my application won't be used in English language.

I need to translate the used keys and words (for example in legend or search) to other language (Slovak for example).

I'm using prefuse.data.Graph and prefuse.data.Tree.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/steps.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't say much about how the multi-language support is made in prefuse. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution... actually, I was looking in a wrong sources.

Legends and panels that needed to be translated were part of the owl2prefuse.jar I was using.

There are those keys hardcoded in the sources.